# How to send multiple documents to DocuSign from Conga Composer

Tags: docusign, congo-composer

We have couple of  requirement's using conga composer

1. Based on the type of product we have to send  multiple documents composed on Congo to Docusign, but currently CongaComposer is allowing only to send one Document Template to Docusign
   [image]
2. We need to read few parameters on the signed document from docusign and store them back on related salesforce records. We are able to do this using custom fields on DocuSign using DocuSign template but we are not able to do so using CongaComposer template.

   Is there any work around to achieve these functionalities

Comment: Interesting. One of the devs from docusign is a regular here. @mikebz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are some parameters in Composer that will allow you to accomplish your requirement.  Your end solution might be a combination of one or both of the following:

&SelectTemplates=1 enables a multi-select menu that would permit you to select (and order) multiple files for merge and distribution to DocuSign ([SelectTemplates KB Article](https://www.congasphere.com/parameters/SelectTemplates.htm))

&TemplateId=Id1,Id2,id3... The template id parameter will accept as many as 10 unique template ids, simply comma-separated ([TemplateId KB Article](https://www.congasphere.com/parameters/TemplateId.htm))